# float right does not work

Tags: html, css

In this example, `float: right` doesn't seem to work. Do I understand it correctly? Isn't div `#col4` supposed to go up to the right side of first box? How can I take it up with `float`? What am I doing wrong?

```css
.sivulla {
  width: 188px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
  height: 194px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#col4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #b9b9b9;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-image: url(kuva1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100%;
  float: right;
}

#content {
  float: right;
}

#col1,
#col2,
#col3,
#col4,
#col5 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>html5 ja css3</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="lopputyylit.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <br>
  <div class="sivulla">
    <span class="isoteksti">Lorem ipsum </span><br><br>dolor sit amet, <br>consectetuer adipiscing elit,
  </div>

  <div class="sivulla">
    <span class="isoteksti">Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br><br> sit amet, consectetuer <br>adipiscing elit
  </div>

  <div class="sivulla">
    <span class="isoteksti">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span><br><br> consectetuer adipiscing elit, <br>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="col4">
      TRANSITION
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: no, you will have this is you move the transition box BEFORE the first box

Comment: if you move your `col4` div before the first `sivulla` div, you can see that it works, you can also put `float:left` on the `sivulla` divs, but in the end, note that float is not the easiest way to do everything ... if you want a menu on the right for example, you could consider putting all of your `sivulla` into a wrapper and working with that

Comment: @Neil could you make those into wrapper and show me how to do it that way ?

Comment: @waleedd32 i could, but i need to know what you really want to achieve, if i tell you about it, it is because i have the feeling tou wand to put a "navbar" on the side of your page, and you will need to adjust it's height every time, you will need to float left every single elements ... i can't really show you a way to do it since it is not the question, but it will look like that : `<div class="main"><div class="sivulla">1</div><div class="sivulla">2</div><div class="sivulla">3</div></div><div class="col4">navbar</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `#col4` element up to where you want it to float: To the top of the page. Floated elements will float wherever you (vertically / in the order of HTML elements / in the document flow) put them (see snippet below).

```css
.sivulla {
  width: 188px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
  height: 194px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#col4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #b9b9b9;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-image: url(kuva1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100%;
  float: right;
}

#content {
  float: right;
}

#col1,
#col2,
#col3,
#col4,
#col5 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>html5 ja css3</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="lopputyylit.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="col4">
      TRANSITION
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="sivulla">
    <span class="isoteksti">Lorem ipsum </span><br><br>dolor sit amet, <br>consectetuer adipiscing elit,
  </div>

  <div class="sivulla">
    <span class="isoteksti">Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br><br> sit amet, consectetuer <br>adipiscing elit
  </div>

  <div class="sivulla">
    <span class="isoteksti">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span><br><br> consectetuer adipiscing elit, <br>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```